# Why am I receiving this error with RazorPage when performing a post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I've run into something I can't seem to figure out using RazorPages and populating a SelectList from a SQL DB. I followed a tutorial on binding data to the select list and now when I post my form it blows up with the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Alternatively, set the 'CarMakeList' property to a non-null value in the 'TestProject.Pages.IndexModel' constructor.

I have the following code:

```
 public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    private readonly IVehicleService _vehicleService;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;


    public IndexModel(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, IVehicleService vehicleService, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        _vehicleService = vehicleService;
        _context = context;

    }

    public Filters Filters { get; set; }

    public SelectList CarMakeList { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        PopulateMakeDropdownList();
        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public IFormFile Upload { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        var file = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads", Upload.FileName);
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await Upload.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }

        HttpContext.Session.SetObject("CurrentFilters", Filters);

        return RedirectToPage("vehicles");
    }

    public void PopulateMakeDropdownList(object selectedMake = null)
    {
        var makeQuery = from m in _context.CarMake
            orderby m.Name
            select m;

        CarMakeList = new SelectList(makeQuery.AsNoTracking(), "MakeId", "Name", selectedMake);
    }

 public class CarMake
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("MakeId")]
    public int MakeId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Filters class

```
public class Filters
{
    [Required]
    public int Source { get; set; }

    public int MmrPercentage { get; set; }

    public int MaximumPrice { get; set; }

    public int MinimumPrice { get; set; }

    public int Transport { get; set; }

    public int Recon { get; set; }

    public int ExtraCost { get; set; }

    public int MinimumOdometer { get; set; }

    public int MaximumOdometer { get; set; }

    public string InitialSortOption { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public string Make { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

My front end looks like this:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Filters.Make">Vehicle Make:</label>
        <select id="makeDropDownList" asp-for="Filters.Make" class="form-control"
                asp-items="@Model.CarMakeList">
            <option value="-1">-- Select Make --</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've been messing around for about an hour and have no idea why this is breaking. It's dying in my startup.cs file in this block of code on the await next.Invoke()

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next.Invoke();

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/AndItsGone");
            }
        });
```

Edit: Everything was working great until I added the Make/Model select lists to the solution. Page loads fine, as soon as I click the submit button I receive the error.

Comment: Can you give us the whole code of the class where the method PopulateMakeDropdownList is a part of?

Comment: this is a nice tutorial :  https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-asp-net-core-razor-pages/

Comment: What is the defination for `Filters.Make`?

Comment: `Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor.`. Could you add the `CarMake` description?

Comment: I have the same problem and can't figure it out.

It seems you have a problem with binding a SelectList and my problem is binding a PagedList.

The error says you can set the property to non-null in the constructor but it doesn't work.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55926657/asp-net-core-razor-model-bound-complex-types-must-not-be-abstract-or-value-typ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this has something to with DI, but I could never come up with what it was. I have adjusted my approach and solved the issue with the following code:

I got rid of the binding of the SelectList to the model and am now doing this:

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        var makeQuery = from m in _context.CarMake
            orderby m.Name
            select m;

        ViewData["Makes"] = makeQuery.Select(n => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = n.MakeId.ToString(),
                Text = n.Name
            }).ToList();

        return Page();
    }
```

And front end code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Filters.Make">Vehicle Make:</label>
        <select id="makeDropDownList" asp-for="Filters.Make" class="form-control"
                asp-items="@((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Makes"])">
            <option value="-1">-- Select Make --</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```